# DBMS_XMLDOM - How to get the ID node?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to get the ID value of a XML node with DBMS_XMLDOM, but I don't know how...

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns2:instrumentosjuridicosActualizacionRespuesta xmlns:ns2="http://dcf.formacion.sepe.es/">
            <origenSolicitud>10</origenSolicitud>
            <retorno>EXCOM000</retorno>
            <descripcion>Éxito en la operación</descripcion>
            <retornoOperacion idBloque="1"><codigo>EXCOM001</codigo><descripcion>Éxito en la operación 1</descripcion></retornoOperacion>
            <retornoOperacion idBloque="2"><codigo>EXCOM002</codigo><descripcion>Éxito en la operación 2</descripcion></retornoOperacion>
        </ns2:instrumentosjuridicosActualizacionRespuesta>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I get the nodes "retornoOperacion"

```
v_nodelist := xslprocessor.selectnodes (xmldom.makenode (v_doc), '//retornoOperacion');
```

And then I can get the items "codigo" and "descripcion"

```
v_node := xmldom.item (v_nodelist, i);
v_item := xslprocessor.valueof (v_node, 'codigo');
v_item := xslprocessor.valueof (v_node, 'descripcion');
```

But I want the value of the `idBloque`. So I want the values "1" and "2"...

Does anybody know how?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of the `idBloque` attribute of the node `v_node`, then use the following:

```
v_item := dbms_xslprocessor.valueof (v_node, '@idBloque');
```

The at-sign (`@`) in an XPath expression is used to indicate that you want the value of the attribute with the name that follows.